# Input Protection

Tags: microcontroller

I have two signal lines that I will be monitoring with an MCU Input I/O pin (3.3v powered). Both inputs will be coming from external sources. I will be monitoring each of them for a high or low state. The problem is that the signal coming in could be between 0v and 24v, and the signals coming in "may" be serial data (approx 9600 baud).

Below is using something like the BAT54SWT1G Schotch Diode Array to clamp voltages at 0v and 3v.

EDIT: Updated schematic with a current limiting resistor before the clamping diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8uMPD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Schematic was redrawn in conventional orientation by Transistor*

Comment: For clamping, you need to limit the input current, so the resistor goes between the input and the clamp.

Comment: If you connect +24V to the input you will likely destroy everything connected to the 3.3V rail.

Comment: Why a simple zener can't do the job? Too slow?

Comment: What exactly does "could be between 0V and 24V" mean? What are the thresholds on that and do you have a guaranteed low level. Your circuit may not work if Vil is much above zero. You may also be better to use opto-couplers for this if the signals are at a distance. Safer too.

Comment: A zener needs significant amount of bias current. If there is any signal resistance, the bias current results in measurement error. A zener is useful with logic inputs that typically have lower source impedance.

Comment: @apaul: I've redrawn your schematic in a conventional manner for readability. Never rotate the ground symbols. They should point down to the, eh, ground. Signal flow should generally be left to right and higher voltages to the top. Delete one schematic and keep the other. (I don't mind.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input signal source resistance is not specified. The clamping diode current flow could be excessive.
You might consider adding a pull-down resistor (or a pull-up resistor) so that the MCU I/O line falls to a known-state when no input signal is connected.
The V1 voltage should be the MCU Vdd power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1GQye.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I like this solution, and it makes sense. I do not have a specified source resistance yet but will work on getting those values. 

I am thinking I would use this exact circuit but instead of the pull-down would use a 1M pull-up to Vdd (MCU's voltage). Am I correct that the max current usage of the clamp @24v input would be approx 2mA?

Comment: Yes, 2 mA.  The single device **BAT54S** could be used (dual-diode, series), instead of two plain BAT54 (single diodes). I had just scaled the time-constant R1C1 to match your original RC. Be aware that the input shouldn't linger at 1.7V - Digital inputs expect quick transitions from low-to-high & high-to-low.

Comment: @apaul Be **certain** than your MCU, and circuits that are powered by its Vdd supply, draw more than this 2mA current at all times, otherwise, your 24V signal source could end up powering, and over-volting the 3.3V supply. Generally, DC regulators are designed to supply current, and *not designed* to sink current - regulator output voltage can rise above 3.3V for the "sinking-current" case.